# WASAPI Exclusive Event Driven skip detection

Tags: wasapi

I have an app that uses WASAPI Exclusive Event Driven mode.  The Microsoft example code for this is not far from what I'm doing.  We have a problem where if the CPU is taxed enough, we skip over one of the 3ms buffers we were supposed to write.  In Exclusive Event driven mode, there appears to be no way to check the write cursor.  In Shared mode, you get GetCurrentPadding(), which does nothing for Exclusive mode.  There is no way to know whether we got behind or skipped ahead or whatever.  I saw that for capture, there is the AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_DATA_DISCONTINUITY flag.  Is there anything similar for IAudioRenderClient?  When I call GetBuffer(), how do I know which play cursor position the pointer I get back corresponds to?  It seems surprisingly easy to simply get out of sync without knowing it.  I could watch the clock and error out if anything funny happens, but I want something more deterministic.  I want to know for sure that we missed a buffer before I barf out to the user.